# Go back from another activity to MainActivity

Tags: java, android-studio, android-activity

From my `MainActivity`, I have a button that takes me to a `Activity A`

now, I have some functions inside `Activity A` that generates some string data.

What I wanted was, after that string data is generated, I want to go back to `MainActivity` with some value from `Activity A` and set that to an EditText.

So I tried this...

In my `MainActivity`, I have a method that will be called when the method in `Activity A` that generates that string data is triggered. It looks like this...

**MainActivity**

```
public void receiveData(String data) { 
     EditText ed = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eText);
     ed.setText(data);
 }
```

**Activity A**

```
MainActivity mainActivity;

public void onCreate() {
   ...
   ...
   mainActivity = new MainActivity();
}

public void generateSomeResult() {
   ...
   ...
   mainActivity.receiveData(some_string_result);

   //I tried calling MainActivity in two ways

   //This one causes MainActivity to not fully load maybe why the EditText is not setting the value.
   Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.this);
   startActivity(intent); 

   //This one causes the MainActivity to fully reload and erased the passed value from Activity A maybe why the value set to EditText has not been set.
   finish(); 
}
```

Now I'm stuck on what to do. Any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `startActivityForResult ()` instead of `startActivity()` and get your result from Activity A in MainActivity using `onActivityResult()`.

Have a look :

1. [startActivityForResult](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int,%20android.os.Bundle))
2. [onActivityResult](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onActivityResult(int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent))